# payment gateway integration for android app of magento site

Tags: android, rest, magento, payment

I am developing android app for my magento site. I am using REST api. I did upto cart page using rest. Payment and order related things integration is challenging for me , since we need more secured and careful module development.I am blank now. Kindly explain the workflow how to do it along with the things i have to keep in mind.

Comment: can you please suggest which payment gaeway u suport in magento?

Comment: authorize.net - I saw some api to integrate between android and authorize.net. But for order related things i struggling how to integrate magento orders part + android + authorize.net...

Comment: I saw how to create orders programatically in magento. But i am struggling how to get details from authorize.net from android and process order on server side..?

Comment: http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/

Answer (score 1):

For answering this properly, you should provide more information about what problem you are facing and what workflow you are fallowing

Anyways, In cart you must be having all the product and their total price sum. What you can do is you can pass all the information to the payment getway. CCAvanue is a batter option to implement getway. They have awesome support. I have written a post [here](http://ashu-hackingforever.blogspot.in/2014/11/hi-there-its-been-days-that-i-have.html) explaing how to integrate CCAvanue.

After transaction you will be notified by the getway in terms of Successful or failure transaction. If you get a success status you can call the magento web-service to update the database and also you can send email to admin and customer in worker thread. And show status of their transaction on a screen

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. We are using magento default authorize.net payment gateway in website. Should i use the same in android app as well..?

Comment: Not really necessary but yes If you use same getway will help you in many ways like support will be there and you don't have to invest money again for mobile payment. [here](http://developer.authorize.net/api/mobile/) they are providing documentation for mobile integration. If this answer helped you please upvote